# Log Monitoring of Multiple Computers with Email Notification - Filter by EventID

Tags: email, powershell, notifications, event-log

I have this PowerShell code below that gathers eventlogs from a list of computers and then sends email to the recipients.

What i do need is for it to look for specific set of event id and not search for all events. Then if it sees any of the event i specified, it will send the report to the user else it would just end and not send any email.

```
# Continue even if there are errors 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";

# EMAIL PROPERTIES 
 # Set the recipients of the report. 
  $rcpts = "user@domain.com" 

# REPORT PROPERTIES 
 # Path to the report 
  $reportPath = "SomePath"; 

 # Report name 
  $reportName = "SomeFileName"; 

# Path and Report name together 
$logReport = $reportPath + $reportName 

# Get computer list to check logs 
$computers = 'servers.txt'

# Date coverage of logs to be monitored
$StartDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

# LogNames to be monitored
$logname = "System"

# Cleanup old files.. 
$Daysback = "-7" 
$CurrentDate = Get-Date; 
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback); 
Get-ChildItem $reportPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item; 

# CSS style
$css= "<style>"
$css= $css+ "BODY{ text-align: center; background-color:white;}"
$css= $css+ "TABLE{    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Sans-Serif;font-size: 12px;margin: 10px;width: 100%;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;border-top: 7px solid #004466;border-bottom: 7px solid #004466;}"
$css= $css+ "TH{font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;padding: 1px;background: #cceeff;border-right: 1px solid #004466;border-left: 1px solid #004466;color: #004466;}"
$css= $css+ "TD{padding: 1px;background: ##FFFFFF;border-right: 1px solid #004466;border-left: 1px solid #004466;color: #669;hover:black;}"
$css= $css+  "TD:hover{ background-color:#e5f7ff;}"
$css= $css+ "</style>" 

# Process logs 
$body = Get-Content $computers | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterHashtable @{logname=$logname; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate}    
}

if ($body)
{
    # Convert to HTML style 
    $body | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $css MachineName,LogName,LevelDisplayName,ID,TimeCreated,Message > $logReport

    # Get-Date for Email Subject
    $subjectDate = get-date -format F

    # EMAIL Properties
    $smtpServer = "smtp.domain.com" 
      $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
      $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
      $msg.To.Add($rcpts) 
            $msg.From = "user@domain.com" 
      $msg.Subject = "EventLog Report for $subjectDate" 
            $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true 
            $msg.Body = get-content $logReport 
      $smtp.Send($msg) 
            $body = "Hello"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting an ID parameter into your Filter Hashtable then use an `If-Else` statement to turn the Id search on and off. Create your text file like soon:

**servers.txt**

```
SERVERNAME1;11,65,73
SERVERNAME2;1
SERVERNAME3;1,2,3,4,5
SERVERNAME4;
SERVERNAME5;
SERVERNAME5;33,64,217,15
```

Note the `;` with no ids on the end of SERVERNAME `4` and `5` this will search for all events.

Then use the following code to pick out the event id's and server names from `servers.txt` and search accordingly.

```
$body = Get-Content $computers | ForEach-Object {

    # Reset Variables
    $EventIds=$ServerName=$split=$null

    # Split the line in the text file on ;
    $split = $_ -split ";"

    # Get the servernamne and eventIds
    $ServerName = $split[0]
    [Array]$EventIds = $split[1] -split ','

    # If there is an event id mentioned search for it else search for all events
    If($EventIds -ne "" -and $EventIds -ne $null){
        Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ServerName -FilterHashtable @{logname=$logname; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate; Id=$EventIds} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    Else{
        Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ServerName -FilterHashtable @{logname=$logname; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate}    
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work. However, 2 things i should point out are,that the set of Event ID i am going to filter is identical with all the servers and if the process didn't see any entry from the set of ID's, the process will end and not search furthermore.

Comment: @lapsantos I have added in an extra foreach loop to search each ID one by one. So that if an ID doesn't have any event it will silently continue onto the next ID.

Comment: @lapsantos turns out you don't need the foreach loop you can just use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` with the array of event ID and it will continue searching. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the help Richard. I've upvoted your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved this one just buy adding a line of code.

Added this `$EventID = Get-Content 'EventID.txt'`

and modified this

```
$body = Get-Content $computers | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterHashtable @{logname=$logname; Level=1,2,3; starttime=$StartDate; ID=$EventID}    
}
```